# correct structure in MVC with spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, javabeans

I'm a little confused about correct mvc pattern.

This is my config file: In this class I've got all Beans.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = " name.web.controller")
@PropertySource("classpath:NewLibrary.properties")
@EnableTransactionManagement

    @Bean
    public UserRepo getUserService() {
        return new UserImpl(getDataSource());
    }
    
    
    @Bean
    public BookRepo getBookService() {
        return new BookImpl(getDataSource());
    }
```

This is my interface UserRepo, and interface UserService. They are the same

```
public interface UserService {
public String getUser();
void add(UserModel u);
UserModel getById(int id);
UserModel getByName(String name);
UserModel getByCognome(String surname);
Optional<UserModel> findOne(int id);
public void insert(User u);
public String giveName();
List<UserModel>ByNome(String nome);
List<UserModel> ByPassAndUsername(String password, String username);

}
```

I've got my class that implemets this interface

```
@Repository
public class UserImpl extends AbstractDao<UserModel, Integer> implements UserRepo {
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
 @Autowired
public UserRepo userRepo;

private JdbcTemplate conn;
@Override
@Transactional
public void add(UserModel u) {
    em.persist(u);
}
public UserImpl(DataSource ds) {
    conn= new JdbcTemplate(ds);
}
@Override
public UserModel getById(int id) {
    return em.find(UserModel.class, id);
}
@Override
public UserModel getByName(String nome) {
    CriteriaBuilder queryBuilder= em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<UserModel> query= 
queryBuilder.createQuery(UserModel.class);
    Root<UserModel> rec= query.from(UseriModel.class);
     
query.select(rec).where(queryBuilder.equal(rec.get("nome"), nome));
     
     UserModel ut=em.createQuery(query).getSingleResult();
     em.clear();
    
     return ut;
    
    //return em.find(UtentiModel.class, nome);
    
};
```

And finally I've got my Controller
In my Controller I @Autowired UsersRepo/*it's a inteface*/.
And my code works, I can do all CRUD operations.

But, was told to me that this is not the right way. I can't autowire  directly.
@Autowired of UserRepo, inside Controller class.
So I search info on web, and I create a Service class.
The Service it's made so: have the same interface with the same methods that I wrote inside UserRepo Inteface. After I create the class that implements that interface, called UserSeviceImpl.

In userServiceImpl I go to @Autowire UserRepo interface, and after I go to @Autowire userService inside the Controller.

But now my code doesn't work, Ive got 404 status in all pages in all Controlles: `The requested resource [/bookProject/] is not available

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.`

I've got no errors inside Console, just info:

```
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
set 30, 2021 5:41:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
set 30, 2021 5:41:10 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
set 30, 2021 5:41:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Server initialization in [624] milliseconds
set 30, 2021 5:41:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
set 30, 2021 5:41:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.50]
set 30, 2021 5:41:12 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
set 30, 2021 5:41:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
set 30, 2021 5:41:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory [/home/viktoriya/Scrivania/apache-tomcat-9.0.50/webapps/ROOT]
 set 30, 2021 5:41:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory [/home/viktoriya/Scrivania/apache-tomcat-9.0.50/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [13] ms
set 30, 2021 5:41:12 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
set 30, 2021 5:41:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in [2050] milliseconds
```

So I can not understand if I'm wrong to Autowire some bean, or if my current pattern is wrong, or if I need to change something in the config class, or if I have not applied the class of service well. Beacuse before my code was working well.

This is my controller:
@Controller
public class UserController {
@Autowired
private UserService us;
List  user;
@GetMapping("/new")
public ModelAndView new(Model model) {

```
UserModel users= new UserModel();
model.addAttribute("utenteForm", user);
return new ModelAndView("client", "utenteForm", new 
UtentiModel());
}
@PostMapping("/add")
public ModelAndView sumbit(@ModelAttribute("utenteForm") UserModel users)
{ us.ad(users);
```

And this is UserServiceImpl:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{
private final static Logger log= 
Logger.getLogger(UserServiceImpl.class.getName());
@Autowired
private UserRepo userRepo;
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
@Override
public void add(UserModel u) {
    userRepo.add(u);
}
@Override
public UserModel getByName(String name) {
    
    return userRepo.getByName(name);
}
```

Comment: Start by verifying that there is, in fact, a controller method that maps to the `bookProject` endpoint. If so, please edit your post to include it.

Comment: Please post your service interface and its implementation, alongwith updated controller.

Comment: @SB done. in the meantime I also tried to change the code and put Autowired of new classes everywhere, but it doesn't work

Comment: @TheHeadRush I added more code to this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say check your path that you are calling against the controller definition. I think it help if you update the code to see also the controller.

Example:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestRestController{

  @Autowired
  private TestService testService;
 .....
}

 @Service
public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService {

  @Autowired    
  private TestRepository testRepository;

}
@Repository
@Transactional
 public class TestRepositoryImpl implements TestRepository{
 
 }
```

Comment: if I delete UserService and UserServiceImpl or If I don't Autowire them, my code starts to work, but in this case they are unused. If I leave this 2 classes and Autowire them into Controller, nothing is work. Neither debug mode. If I Autowire this new class inside Controller I've got 500 staus, not found bean. If I don't Autowire UserRepo inside controller, anything is works. So I think It's a problem with bean, but don't know where exactly is the problem. changing autowiring of new classes I've got errors ranging from 404 to 500.

Comment: I can write you here a small way how you can define the controller, service, repository and then you can compare it with your code. It can also help you to set the loglevel on debug maybe is silently failing.

Comment: yes please. I'll check where I went wrong

Comment: I added to my answer because it was not possible to put it here in comments. I hope it helps. Otherwise I think I need to see more code.

Comment: If I add to my code public TestServiceImpl(TestRepository testRepository) {
    this.testRepository = testRepository; I've got:Error creating bean, and doesn't work anything. If I add just "private TestRepository testRepository;", my app works but got NUllPointException in add method. But the search by filter method ,it's workin

Comment: Can you put @Autowired on the testRepository in the service?